# Inserting two separate text files input into a linked list that holds two values at each node

Tags: java

Okay so I have to have to create a Linked List that asks the user for text file names (I already imported the text files, just prompting the user for them). The files are just lists of numbers but the system has to interact with two of them at a time. At each node, the system has to store one variable from each list (two total). My code is complete but when I run it, it doesn't prompt me for the lists, just prints an empty Linked List, what should I do?

Here is my FileIn class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
//import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileIn 
{

    String fname1, fname2;

    public void fileIn() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        getFileName();
        readFileContents();
    }

    public void readFileContents() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        InputStream input1 = new FileInputStream(new File(fname1));
        InputStream input2 = new FileInputStream(new File(fname2));

        boolean loop;
        BufferedReader in1, in2;
        String x, y = null;
        int j, k, length;
        //char ch;

        try
        {
            in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input1));
            in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input2));
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

            loop = true;
            while(loop)
            {
                if(null == (x = in1.readLine()) && null == (y =     in2.readLine()))
                {
                    loop = false;
                    in1.close();
                    in2.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("line = "+ x + " " + y);
                    j = 0;
                    k = 0;
                    length = x.length();
                    while((x = in1.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("line["+j+"] = " +x.charAt(j));
                    }
                    while((y = in2.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("line["+k+"] = " +y.charAt(k));
                    }
                }
                list.insertBack(x, y);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        }
    }

    public void getFileName()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first file name: ");
        fname1 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter second file name: ");
        fname2 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("File name entered was " + fname1);
        System.out.println("File name entered was " + fname2);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Here is my Node class

```
public class Node 
{
    private String x, y;
    private Node next;

    public Node(String x, String y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public String getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public String getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n)
    {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

Here is my LinkedList class:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class LinkedList 
{
    public Node head;
    //private int n;
    private double size, meanX, meanY, stanDevX, stanDevY, sumX, sumY, sqSumX, 
                    sqSumY, xTimesYsum, r, rSq, slope, intercept, regression;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        FileIn f = new FileIn();
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        System.out.println(list.showList());
    }

    public LinkedList()
    {
        this.head = null;
    }

    public void insertBack(String x, String y)
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(x, y);
        }
        else
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(x, y);
            Node curr = head;
            while(curr.getNext() != null)
            {
                curr = curr.getNext();
            }
            curr.setNext(newNode);
            size++;
        }
    }

    public String showList()
    {
        int i = 0;
        String retStr = "List nodes:\n";
        Node curr = head;
        while(curr != null)
        {
            i++;
            retStr += "Node " + i + ": " + curr.getX() + ", " + curr.getY() + "\n";
            curr = curr.getNext();

        }
        return retStr;
    }

    public double getXsum()
    {
        sumX = 0;
        Node curr = head;
        while(curr != head)
        {
            String text = curr.getX();
            double k = Double.parseDouble(text);
            sumX += k;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
        return sumX;
    }

    public double getYsum()
    {
        sumY = 0;
        Node curr = head;
        while(curr != head)
        {
            String text = curr.getY();
            double k = Double.parseDouble(text);
            sumY += k;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
        return sumY;
    }

    public double calcMeanX()
    {
        getXsum();
        meanX = 0;

        meanX = sumX/size;
        return meanX;
    }

    public double calcMeanY()
    {
        getYsum();
        meanY = 0;

        meanY = sumY/size;
        return meanY;
    }

    public double getSqSumX()
    {
        calcMeanX();
        sqSumX = 0;
        Node curr = head;
        while(curr != null)
        {
            String text = curr.getX();
            double k = Double.parseDouble(text);
            sqSumX += (k-meanX)*(k-meanX);
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
        return sqSumX;
    }

    public double getSqSumY()
    {
        calcMeanY();
        sqSumY = 0;
        Node curr = head;
        while(curr != null)
        {
            String text = curr.getY();
            double k = Double.parseDouble(text);
            sqSumY += (k-meanY)*(k-meanY);
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
        return sqSumY;
    }

    public double calcStdX()
    {
        calcMeanX();
        getSqSumX();

        stanDevX = Math.sqrt(sqSumX/(size-1));
        return stanDevX;
    }

    public double calcStdY()
    {
        calcMeanY();
        getSqSumY();

        stanDevY = Math.sqrt(sqSumY/(size-1));
        return stanDevY;
    }

    public double getxTimesYsum()
    {
        xTimesYsum = 0;
        Node curr = head;
        while(curr != null)
        {
            String text1 = curr.getX();
            String text2 = curr.getY();
            double k1 = Double.parseDouble(text1);
            double k2 = Double.parseDouble(text2);
            xTimesYsum += (k1 * k2);
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
        return xTimesYsum;
    }

    public double calcCorrelation()
    {
        r = 0;
        getXsum();
        getYsum();
        getSqSumX();
        getSqSumY();
        getxTimesYsum();

        r = (size * xTimesYsum - sumX * sumY)/
                (Math.sqrt((size * sqSumX - (sumX*sumX)) * (size * sqSumY - (sumY * sumY))));
        return r;
    }

    public double calcCorrelationSq()
    {
        rSq = 0;
        calcCorrelation();
        rSq = (r * r);
        return rSq;
    }

    public double calcSlope()
    {
        slope = 0;

        getxTimesYsum();
        calcMeanX();
        calcMeanY();
        getSqSumX();

        slope = ((xTimesYsum) - (size * meanX * meanY))/
                ((sqSumX) - (size * (meanX * meanX)));
        return slope;
    }

    public double calcIntercept()
    {
        intercept = 0;

        calcMeanX();
        calcMeanY();
        calcSlope();

        intercept = meanY - (slope * meanX);
        return intercept;
    }

    public double calcRegression()
    {
        regression = 0;

        calcIntercept();
        calcSlope();
        calcMeanX();

        regression = intercept + (slope * meanX);
        return regression;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first step in solving your problem will be to isolate your problem, meaning it's time to do some serious debugging, either with a debugger that will allow you to step through your code and analyze variables as the program progresses, or with a logger, or with a "poor man's debugger" -- a lot of println statements that expose variable state as the program progresses. Much luck!

Comment: Also please have a look at: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you